# get part of an email follow a pattern

Tags: python, string

Input: abc@xyz.com

Output: xyz

my code is below

```
email = "123@helloworld.com"
new_email = email.split('@')[1]
domain = new_email.split('.')[0]
```

Please help me with other methods to get the part of it?

Comment: I wonder using for in range(len(string)). However, this way is such taking time.

Comment: What have you already tried, and what do you need help with exactly? Are you familiar with regex? Why can't you use your existing code? If this is homework, please read [How to ask and answer homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/4518341). In either case, please read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE** (Based on a comment, see below)

If you have input like `123@helloworld.python.com` or `123@helloworld.yahoo`. And you want to extract only `helloworld`. You can use

```py
result = re.search(r'@([^\.]+)\.', email).group(1)
```

**BEFORE UPDATE**

You can use `re` module.

```py
import re

email = email = '123@helloworld.com'
result = re.search(r'@(.+)\.com$', email)
if result:
    result = result.group(1)

print(result)
```

Output:

```
helloworld
```

If you are sure that you will always have something in between `@` and `.com`. You can remove `if statement`.

```py
import re

email = email = '123@helloworld.com'
result = re.search(r'@(.+)\.com$', email).group(1)

print(result)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It such a brilliant answer

Comment: You know. It is very specific and brief for me. I have search tons of resources before I post a question. Finally, you save me here. Once again you are amazing

Comment: Hi @BhusalC_Bipin, I wonder that follow '.' is any characters. How would I extract the patern of the email.
example:  '123@helloworld.zyz.com', abc@fkdddddd.yahoo
How would I only able get domain between @ and .

Comment: Hi @BrianHuynh you can use ```result = re.search(r'@([^\.]+)\.', email).group(1)```